# Creating a block diagonal matrix when the submatrices in the diagonal are unknown

Tags: matrix, expression-construction

Let us assume that we have an integer $j$ $(j=1,2,...,k)$ and that for every $j$ is generated a matrix $P$ of dimensions $j$x$j$ . For example, if $j=1$ then $P=(-2)$.

If $j=2$ then

$$R = \begin{pmatrix} -2 & 1 \\ 0 & -2 \end{pmatrix}$$

If $j=3$ then

$$R = \begin{pmatrix} -2 & 1 &0 \\ 0 & -2 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -2 \end{pmatrix}$$
and so forth.

I want to construct a block diagonal matrix $J$ with all the matrices $P$ (which have been generated before, in the iteration of $j$) in the diagonal elements. I suppose that `ArrayFlatten` and `DiagonalMatrix` should be used but I don't know in what way. Any help appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> (P /@ Range[n])]
```

If `P` produces `SparseArrays`, this does not seem to work. Then one can either convert to dense arrays with `Normal` like this

```
SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> (Normal@*P /@ Range[n])]
```

or one can emply the undocumented function `` SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix `` as follows:

```
SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix[{#, #} -> P[#] & /@ Range[5]]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this turns out the result I want.

Comment: You did not tell us that `P` produces `SparseArray`s. Apparently, one has to convert to dense arrays with `Normal`, first.

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
Clear["`*"];
jordan[j_ /; j >= 2] := 
 SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> -2, Band[{1, 2}] -> 1}, {j, j}]
jordan[j_ /; j == 1] := {{-2}};
n = 5;
SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> Table[jordan[j] // Normal, {j, 1, n}]}, 
 Sum[j, {j, 1, n}]]
% // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Oh yes this is really helpful to me.You understood exactly what I meant!

Comment: One more question. If I don't have -2 in every matrix but for j=1 I have {{-1}}, for j=2 I have {{1,1},{0,1}}, for j=3 {{-2,1,0},{0,-2,1},{0,0,-2}},... (every  matrix is different) then what should I do ?

Comment: @arod  `R1 = {{-2}};
R2 = {{1, 1}, {0, 1}};
R3 = {{-2, 1, 0}, {0, -2, 1}, {0, 0, -2}};
SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> Normal /@ {R1, R2, R3}}];
% // Normal // MatrixForm`

Comment: The matrices I mentioned are random. I do not know the matrices in each iteration of j. How can what you said be done in a more general case?

Comment: How to generate the matrices which your mention? You can edit your question and add another imformation about your new problem.

Comment: Just something to point out: it's dangerous/bad practice to put a blanket ``Clear["`*"]`` on a public forum where people copy/paste to see what your code is doing before reading it. Only `Clear` the symbols you really need to clear. I now have to go back and recover the state of some interactive work I was doing...

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thanks your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

*"I suppose that `ArrayFlatten` and `DiagonalMatrix` should be used but I don't know in what way."*

Other answers show that `ArrayFlatten` or `DiagonalMatrix` are not needed. But, in case you wish to use them, here is a way:

```
P[n_] /; n > 1 := -2 IdentityMatrix[n] + 
   DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1, n - 1], 1];
P[1] = {{-2}};

n = 5;

MatrixForm @ 
 ArrayFlatten[DiagonalMatrix[Range @ n] /. i_Integer?Positive :> P @ i]
```

[image]

You can also use   `ArrayFlatten` + `IdentityMatrix`:

```
plist = P /@ Range[n];

MatrixForm @ 
 ArrayFlatten[IdentityMatrix[n] /. 1 :> Last[plist = RotateLeft[plist]]]
```

> ```
>  same picture
> ```

Both methods work with arbitrary list of matrices,

```
Q[{n_, m_}] := Array[Subscript[x, Row @ {##}] &, {n, m}];

SeedRandom[1]
qlist = Table[Q @ RandomInteger[{2, 6}, 2], n];

MatrixForm @ 
 ArrayFlatten[DiagonalMatrix[Range @ n] /. i_Integer?Positive :> qlist[[i]]]
```

[image]

```
MatrixForm @ 
 ArrayFlatten[IdentityMatrix[n] /. 1 :> Last[qlist = RotateLeft[qlist]]]
```

> ```
>  same picture
> ```

Comment: No it was not necessary for me to use ArrayFlatten and DiagonalMatrix but I thought these commands should be used - I didn't know about Band. Anyway, thank you, your method works fine!

Answer (score 1):

```
Table[Which[x + 1 == y, 1, x == y, -2, True, 0], {x, 0, #}, {y, 0, #}] &@5
```

> {{-2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -2, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -2, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
> 0, -2, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, -2, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2}}